# Evaluating $\lim _{x\to\pi/2}\left( \sin x\right)^{\log x}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, logarithms

This math has $\log x$ as power of the $\sin x$ trigonometric function.

> $$\lim _{x\to\pi/2}\left( \sin x\right)^{\log x}$$

Comment: Use exponential form $A^B = \exp(B\log(A))$ when $A>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is continuous at $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Hence,

$$\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\sin x\right)^{\log x} =1^{\log \frac{\pi}{2}} = 1 $$